# Component won't stay wrapped within bounds (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make my own tab navigation like Instagram has [instagram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3TL7.png). I noticed that the items within the footer view I made does not stay within the bounds and moves to the top left of the screen. *Images shown* - [What I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKiM9.png) [What happens frequently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sphv6.png)

Here is the most important part of my code. I have done inline styles temporarily to try and figure out the issue. Here is the part where the issue lays `<View style = {{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, backgroundColor: '#fff', height: 80}} <TouchableOpacity  onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')} style = {{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}> 
  <Text style = {{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}> Profile </Text> 
  </TouchableOpacity>  </View>`-

render() {
    return (

```
<MapView  style = {[style.container, style.map]}
  region = {this.state.initialPosition}>

  <MapView.Marker coordinate = {this.state.markerPosition}> 

  <View style = {style.radius}> 
  <View style = {style.marker}/>
  </View>

  </MapView.Marker>
  <View style = {{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, backgroundColor: '#fff', height: 80}} >

  <TouchableOpacity  onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')} style = {{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}> 
  <Text style = {{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}> Profile </Text> 
  </TouchableOpacity>

   </View>
  </MapView>

);
```

}
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    //alignItems: 'center',
  },

text: {
      color: '#fff'
  },

map: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute'
    },

```
radius:{

  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  borderRadius: 50 / 2,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,213,106,0.3)',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'rgba(1,213,106,0.3)',
  alignItems:'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
},

marker: {
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: '#fff',
  borderRadius: 20 / 2,
  borderWidth: 3,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  backgroundColor: '#01D56A'

},
```

menuSection: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height/3,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

icon:{
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
})

Comment: Please edit the question and **format** the code segments in code view using **Ctrl + k**, so that the question can be understood clearly. Thanks for the understanding.